# Differencies in Mex-file for Matlab

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-deployment, fixed-point, matlab-engine

I have created a Mex-file (.mexw64) from my matlab project using Matlab Coder. The problem is that the output is not the same when I run the mex-file as when I run the project in a normal way. Often the variation in the numbers are really small:

5.4463..  ->  5.4465.. etc.

I'm thinking that there might be a problem related fixed point computations. **What should I look for?**

Comment: You have an m-script file that acts one way when executed and another way when compiled as an executable, is this correct?  Where does the fixed-pointing com into play?

Comment: Hehe. Maybe it doesn't. I do not know why the behaviour is different. What may the reasons be? Thankful for your help.

Comment: I'm thinking there is no fixed-pointing difference.  When we start talking about differences in the 4th decimal place, I'd say it's the difference between interpreted m-script and compiled C code.  I'd guess the C code is more correct, but it's just a guess

Comment: But as the code is written in Matlab and then turned into c-code with Matlab Coder it is the Matlab-code that is _"correct"_ in the sense that I wish to emulate this code exactly. Could it have anything to do with the `extrinsic functions` I have, or is it some sort of internal translation error?

Comment: I have been printing along the way of the execution and found differencies like these in the prints. 0.449101628450606  ->    0.449101628450607 it is just in the last decimal that the mex-execution is of by 1.. But it would be strange if this rounding error produced so severe differencies as those that occur later..

Comment: More information is needed here. Did you mean floating point? Source could help. I used to run molecular dynamics simulations, and using a code that isn't careful, the length of a simulation can be limited by the accumulation of round-off errors.

Comment: This is why numerical analysis exists. There may be a significant difference in the result when operations are executed in different sequence. (a+b)*c is not always same as a*c + b*c.

Answer (score 0):

Expected differences from MATLAB are explained in the documentation.  See the section on Floating-point Numerical results:

[MATLAB Coder Documentation on expected differences.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/eml/ug/bsg3gz6.html)